References for Bulk-Boundary correspondence
I have been reading the Quantum Hall Effect from Prof. David Tong's lecture notes. In the Edge Mode chapter, he talked about Bulk-Boundary correspondence where he reproduces the Laughlin wavefunctions. I have looked for other references for this topic but could not find any that do not include Conformal Field Theory. Can anyone suggest some other reference for this topic, considering that I don't know Conformal Field Theory?

They will close your question if you do not specify at least that 3 things in the refered link! 1. What the book covers (that you did) 2. How it covers it — is it rigorous? Intuitive? How is the writer's style? (do it!!) 3. What are the prerequisites? (do it, even if it is trivial)
